# data.table retains previous column data type when replaced with a vector of length 1

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with one column of characters.

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(a = letters[1:10])
dt
#     a
# 1:  a
# 2:  b
# 3:  c
# 4:  d
# 5:  e
# 6:  f
# 7:  g
# 8:  h
# 9:  i
# 10: j
```

I want to replace this with integers and do so like this:

```r
dt[, a := 1:10]
dt
#     a
# 1:  1
# 2:  2
# 3:  3
# 4:  4
# 5:  5
# 6:  6
# 7:  7
# 8:  8
# 9:  9
# 10: 10

class(dt$a)
# [1] "integer"
```

I now have a column of integers. Great!

---

But say I want to do this with a single integer.

```r
dt <- data.table(a = letters[1:10])
dt
#     a
# 1:  a
# 2:  b
# 3:  c
# 4:  d
# 5:  e
# 6:  f
# 7:  g
# 8:  h
# 9:  i
# 10: j

dt[, a := 42]
dt
#      a
# 1:  42
# 2:  42
# 3:  42
# 4:  42
# 5:  42
# 6:  42
# 7:  42
# 8:  42
# 9:  42
# 10: 42
class(dt$a)
# [1] "character"
```

Why does the column retain the original data type of the column?

I realise that I can use `rep(42, 10)` to workaround the issue, but I want to understand *why* the issue exists in the first place. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Interesting. A _workaround_: `dt[, a := rep(42, .N)]`

Comment: See _plonk syntax_ in **Details** of `?:=`